# Evaluate complex number ratio

Tags: complex-numbers

$$ \frac{35887+j(1050)}{-2824+j(-17)} \ = \  ?  $$

This above number is supposed to be the sprung mass response factor to road input at frequency of 6.91 radians/second for the front suspension of a 1958 Jaguar XK150S as per the equation given in Prof. Gillespie's "Fundamentals of Vehicle Dynamics" (1992 Edition) on page 150. I get the answer of "12.70" which is about 4 times the correct answer of "3.16" (as determined by an equation for the same factor as given in Prof. Dukkipati's "Road Vehicle Dynamics"). The question is "what does the above complex number ratio equal?" (am I evaluating it wrong?)...

Brian Paul Wiegand, PE

Comment: Does $j(1050)$ mean $1050 \cdot \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: That's exactly what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Take two complex numbers $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$. To compute $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ note that

$$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}=\frac{(a+bi)\cdot\overline{c+di}}{(c+di)\cdot\overline{c+di}}=\frac{(a+bi)\cdot(c-di)}{(c+di)\cdot(c-di)}=\frac{(ac+bd)+i(bc-ad)}{c^2+d^2}$$

Thus

$$\frac{35887+j(1050)}{-2824+j(-17)}=\frac{(35887\cdot(-2824)+1050\cdot(-17))+j(1050\cdot(-2824)-35887\cdot(-17))}{2824^2+17^2}\approx-12.709-j(0.295)$$

I confirmed this answer with Wolfram Alpha. Perhaps there is an error with the listed correct answer.

Comment: As an integration to the previous answer, note that we have to consider not only the possibility that the listed correct answer of 3.16 is wrong, but also the possibility that an error is present in the  given Gillespie's formula.

Comment: That is what I think, that the Gillespie formula may contain a typo. This would seem to be likely, given that there ia a definate typo in one of the three equations presented.

Comment: I e-mailed the great man himself at the U. of Michigan, but of course I recieved no response. I also e-mailed another professor at the Malaysian U. of Tech who teaches a course in Automotive Dynamics; his ride analysis class uses Gillespie's formulas, but I recieved no response there either.

Comment: I am a little perplexed by "dleggas" answer, as the result per my calculations is just "12.7"; the gain or transmissibility factor for road input to the sprung mass is just a dimensionless real number. However, a value of "12.7" is way too high, and Dukkipati confirms that as wrong with a "3.16" using his equation. It is all very distressing when a source relied upon the world over seems to be incorrect. Anyway, you guys seem pretty sharp and I thank you all for your help.

Comment: Dleggas: I tried to vote up your answer but the system says I don't have enough reputation to do that yet. I'm sorry about that. I'm pretty sure you are correct since we both got the real part: "12.709"; in engineering the imaginary portion "-j(0.0295)" is probably just ignored (in solving the equation for maximum lateral acceleration there is two roots to the quadratic, one of which is negative and consequently just ignored, so there is precedent of sorts).

Comment: @user161845 that is no problem, I hope it was of some help, anyway. Perhaps you are correct in that the small imaginary portion is ignored, though I am not sure what values are considered negligible in this context.

Comment: Dleggas, you were very helpful as now I know the problem lies with the equations and not my evaluation of them. Thanks for all your kind help...161845

Comment: @user161845 Glad you resolved your issue! Cheers